# AWS vs Firebase [Content Delivery Network]

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, firebase, cdn

Let's say I have a **single page application using React/Node**, and I want to deploy that application using a *content delivery network* to improve load performance.

To do that in **Amazon Web Services** (AWS) I would need to incorporate different services to work together.

I would need to host my bundled static web page files on amazon's S3 bucket. Then I would need to host my Node API on Elastic Beanstalk. Lastly, I would then need to setup a CloudFront distribution and set my origin to my S3 bucket.

It would look something like this:

[image]

Now, if I wanted to do the same thing in **Firebase**, according to [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8), I can simply setup *Firebase Hosting* which is backed by their own CDN which gives similar improved load times. Firebase hosting can encompass the entire React/Node application without the need for separation or various services like I did in AWS.

**My questions are:**

1. How does Firebase hosting encompass dynamic Node Apps with out the need to separate the front and backend or use various other services?
2. The point of a CDN is to cache files, so it wouldn't be possible to use a CDN on a Node API right or wrong? If right then how is Firebase using Node app in their CDN?
3. It seems much simpler to setup on Firebase to serve an entire dynamic app on their CDN compared to AWS, would their be any drawbacks to this or is it just a better service?

Comment: *"... without the need to separate the front and backend or use various other services?"*  Marketing spin?  Look at the pricing elements. There certainly appear to be multiple services involved.

Comment: Running node in AWS definitely does not require Elastic Beanstalk. EB is probably the easiest way to get an _existing_ application into AWS. If starting from scratch you can create a node application that can scale very well by using Lambda/DynamoDB - no servers to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Hosting is only for your static frontend code. But there is a way to connect Firebase Hosting and Cloud Functions to serve dynamic content that is pretty easy to setup. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions

You can think of Firebase Hosting a zero-ish config equivalent to the AWS S3/CloudFront section of the diagram.